# practicing WHERE and HAVING in SQL

Tags: sql

here is the schema:

[alt text http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/3324/123vk.jpg](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/3324/123vk.jpg)

here is the question:

Point out the battles in which at least three ships from the same country took part.

here is my answer:

```
  SELECT battles.name 
    FROM battles,
         outcomes,
         ships,
         classes 
   WHERE outcomes.ship = ships.name 
GROUP BY battles.name 
  HAVING COUNT(classes.country) >= 3;
```

Can you please tell me why it is wrong and help me to correct it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT battle
  FROM outcomes, ships, classes
 WHERE outcomes.ship = ships.name AND ships.class = classes.class
 GROUP BY battle
HAVING COUNT(outcomes.ship) >= 3;
```

This will work for your question.

Answer (score 6):

This:

```
SELECT battles.name 
  FROM battles,
       outcomes,
       ships,
       classes 
 WHERE outcomes.ship = ships.name
```

...fundamentally flawed because there's only join criteria between the `OUTCOMES` and `SHIPS`.  The result is a cartesian product.  It's *valid* ANSI-89 syntax, but won't return a resultset remotely resembling what you would expect.

If you only want the battle "name", use:

```
  SELECT o.battle
    FROM OUTCOMES o
    JOIN SHIPS s ON s.name = o.ship
    JOIN CLASSES c ON c.class = s.class
GROUP BY o.battle
  HAVING COUNT(c.country) >= 3
```

If you want the battle table details, use:

```
SELECT b.*
 FROM BATTLES b
 JOIN (SELECT o.battle
         FROM OUTCOMES o
         JOIN SHIPS s ON s.name = o.ship
         JOIN CLASSES c ON c.class = s.class
     GROUP BY o.battle
       HAVING COUNT(c.country) >= 3) x ON x.battle = b.name
```

Comment: what does O and S and C stand for?

Comment: @every_answer_gets_a_point: They are table aliases, so you don't have to re-type the full table name every time you want to show which table you are referencing.

Comment: @OMG Ponies,  I don't think this assert that there were 3 ships from the same country.  It merely checks that there were 3 ships (possibly from 3 different countries, if somehow the "distinct" is implied.)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Hum..., surprising. Again, I wasn't challenging the syntax, but the fact that the query would likely return a battle where you had say a ship from Italy, another from France and another one from the UK, even though none of the countries had 3 ship there.

Comment: @mjv: I understand what you believe should be occurring, but you should really test it yourself if you don't accept that I tested as diligently as you.  If I added `c.country` to the SELECT list, I would see the country with three or more ships attached to an outcome record.

Comment: @OMG: quite fair! I _should_ test for myself, and typically would; I wasn't in the position to do this lately, being on the road, with my "mySQL box" back at home. I hope I didn't offend you with what may have seen like a challenge. I've come to respect your authority on SO, in particular with SQL related questions and indeed upvoted you a few times [I'm a cheap upvoter on the whole].  That's indeed because of my trust in your expertise that I quesionned the results as they seemed odd to me and could have been the result of a misunderstanding.  Cheers!  (and +1 for the "pain") ;-)

Comment: @mjv: It doesn't have to be MySQL - no vendor has been identified, and the query is portable.  I'm flattered, but I'd rather learn if I'm not correct and I do appreciate code review.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DISTINCT BattleName
FROM (
   SELECT Battles.name AS BattleName, Class.Country, COUNT(*)
   FROM Battles
   JOIN Outcomes ON battles.name = Outcomes.battle 
   JOIN Ships ON Outcomes.ship = Ships.name
   JOIN Classes ON Ships.class = Class.class
   GROUP BY battles.name, Classes.country 
   HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
)
```

The main flaw in the original query was that the joins between tables weren't expressed, resulting in plain cartesian product.

Another problem was that the country wasn't  listed to allow a count of ship *per country*.  This modified query was then made the subquery, to allow selecting the BattleName only once.

Notes:
 - I added the COUNT(*) in the SELECT list. This is more by safety/ignorance, I think that some SQL implementation would require the aggregate value found in the HAVING clause to exist in the SELECT list.  (I may be wrong on this).
 - Rather than `COUNT(*)` one may need to use say COUNT(Classes.country) or any other field  (if this this MS-Access as it appears, the `COUNT(*)` syntax may not be allowed).

Comment: As is, this will return an error - there's a comma in the `FROM` statement, likely carried over from converted from ANSI-89 syntax.  `COUNT (*)` in the SELECT is redundant/unused, and there really isn't a need for a subquery/derived table/inline view.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thank you for pointing out the typo.  I'll also try your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT 
   battles.name 
 FROM battles,
      outcomes,
      ships,
      classes 
 WHERE battles.name=outcome.battle 
 AND   outcomes.ship = ships.name 
 AND   ships.class=classes.class
 GROUP BY battles.name
 HAVING COUNT(classes.country) >= 3;
```

Comment: This doesn't assert the requirement that 3 ships _from the same country_ were there.  I think that the only way to do this is to introduce country as one of the group by columns.

Comment: Works, even if it is ANSI-89 join syntax

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select distinct A.battle
from
(select country, o.battle from outcomes o
left join ships s
on s.name = o.ship
left join classes c 
on c.class = s.class  
group by o.battle, country
having count(country) >= 3) A
```

Answer (score 0):

I have quite never used the HAVING clause of the GROUP BY statement. However, GROUP BY should be used for aggregation purposes only. So, if you have no agregation function (SUM, MAX, MIN, AVG, COUNT, etc.) selected, you will not be able to GROUP BY.

Comment: no, you will still be able to use GROUP BY even without those functions as long as the selected columns are also in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: +1 Comment. This must be that I have never seen the use of GROUP BY without aggregation functions. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

You have messed the joins on the tables. You can't just list the tables, you have to specify how they join together

```
From Battles
Inner Join Outcomes On Outcomes.Battle = Battles.name
Inner Join Ships.Name On Ship.Name = Outcomes.Ship
Inner Join Classes.Class = Ship.Class
```

Comment: doesnt work: SELECT battles.name FROM Battles
Inner Join Outcomes On Outcomes.Battle = Battles.name
Inner Join Ships.Name On Ships.Name = Outcomes.Ship
Inner Join Classes.Class = Ships.Class
 WHERE outcomes.ship = ships.name GROUP BY battles.name HAVING count(classes.country) >= 3

Answer (score 0):

I can't see you image (filtered out by big brother)

However, just remember, `WHERE` filters the entire pool of rows first, `GROUP BY` combines those remaining rows, and `Having` filters those groups.

`FROM` & `JOIN`s determine & filter rows
`WHERE` more filters on the rows
`GROUP BY` combines those rows into groups
`HAVING` filters groups
`ORDER BY` arranges the remaining rows/groups